# Add dynamic text on uilabel programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

```
-(void)subImagetap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)subimagetap
{
    UIView *myV = (UIView *)subimagetap.view ;


    NSArray *lbarray = subimagetap.view.subviews;
    for (UIView *textV in lbarray) {
        UILabel *textlb = (UILabel *)textV;
        if([textlb isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            NSLog(@"%@", textlb.text);
            textlb.text = @"Tapped";
        }
    }

}
```

The above mentioned code is my UITapGestureRecognizer code through with I tap on a label and changed his text to "Tapped" but my requirement is when I tap on the label the textpad of iphone will open and i could able to put text in that label.

Comment: You should use `UITextFiled` instead of `UILabel`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use UITextFields if you want the user to be able to directly manipulate their content. Using a text field, you can still do what you're doing by modifying the `text` property, but UITextField supports editing with the keyboard as well.

You can even dress the text field up to look just like a UILabel through use of its `borderStyle` property. (Set it to `UITextBorderStyleNone`)